# Don't show a ghost for draggable element

Tags: css, html, draggable

How can I not show a "ghost" when a draggable element is dragged?

For example, drag this element. It will show a ghost:

```
<div 
  draggable="true" 
  style="background: red; height: 100px; width: 100px;">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html has got what you are looking for.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan - I've been trying out different solutions, still haven't found one that removes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code pen [link](http://codepen.io/n457/pen/GZpqvP) it's using sortable.js.

```js
   // will be a DOM object.
var dragGhost = {};

var hiddenDragGhostList = new Sortable(document.getElementById('hidden-drag-ghost-list'), {
  // Just for appearance
  animation: 150,
  
  setData: function (dataTransfer, dragEl) {
    // Create the clone (with content)
    dragGhost = dragEl.cloneNode(true);
    // Stylize it
    dragGhost.classList.add('hidden-drag-ghost');
    // Place it into the DOM tree
    document.body.appendChild(dragGhost);
    // Set the new stylized "drag image" of the dragged element
    dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragGhost, 0, 0);
  },
  // Don't forget to remove the ghost DOM object when done dragging
  onEnd: function () {
    dragGhost.parentNode.removeChild(dragGhost);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Hidden drag ghost list */
#hidden-drag-ghost-list li {
  /* Note that you can specify "width" & "height" to avoid potential clone incorrect size */
  
  /* Just for appearance */
  background-color: #98dfaf;
  border: 1px solid #5fb49c;
}
.hidden-drag-ghost {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>


<h1>Hidden drag ghost</h1>
<ul id="hidden-drag-ghost-list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Refrences:

1) [blog](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html)

2) [github page](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/794)

Note: All credit goes to the writer I'm only pointing in the right direction.